# can not connect to postgres from Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, hadoop, hbase

I have a docker image in which i have hadoop cluster composed fo one master and two slaves. On this cluster, I have HBase.

**I'm trying to migrate my postgres Database which is installed on my local machine to HBase Database which is on the Docker image  using scoop .**

For postgres, this is my `postgresql.conf` configuration file:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart) port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart) unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list
of directories
                                        # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name


# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min          # 1s-600s ssl = on
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_dh_params_file = '' ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem' ssl_key_file =
'/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
#ssl_ca_file = ''
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#password_encryption = md5              # md5 or scram-sha-256
#db_user_namespace = off
#row_security = on

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0                # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0            # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0               # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                                        # 0 selects the system default
```

Also this is the content of `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections: host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections: host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege. 
local   replication     all                              trust 

host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32     trust      
host    replication     all             ::1/128
```

my problem is when I try to connect to postgres from docker image using scoop using this command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mimic --username postgres --password 0000 --table admission_ids --hbase-table mimic --column-family admission_ids --hbase-row-key id -m 1
```

I just have this problem:

```
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster
is accepting TCP/IP connections. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and
that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

After a search, I jsut understand that docker is the origin of this issue, and to confirm that, I just try to connect to postgres using tenlnet from my local machine in the first time and this is the result :

```
telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

and from the docker for the second time  :

```
telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address
```

my docker image is named spark-hadoop.

I tried to trun this command but always not working:

```
docker run -d --name bridgeToHadoop --publish=127.0.0.1:5432:5432 -p 172.18.0.2:5432:5432 spark-hadoop
```

Comment: can you share logs and errors so its possible to understand what's not working?

Comment: this is the erorr that I found when I try to connect to the postgres using sqoop 
   19/10/22 10:56:04 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql running on host machine and you are trying to connect it from docker container. When you do this, host shouldn't be `localhost` in connection string. Here localhost means docker container.

Replace localhost with IP address, it should be following

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://host-pi-addr:5432/mimic --username postgres --password 0000 --table admission_ids --hbase-table mimic --column-family admission_ids --hbase-row-key id -m 1
```

Comment: even i pass the heost ip address which is 172.20.22.236  I have the same error :

Comment: even I put my host ip address I have the same error **19/10/22 10:56:04 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
**

Answer (score 0):

Docker uses a default 172.17.0.0/16 subnet IP range for container networking.  You need to allow non-local connections because your container network is no longer seen as local with respect to the postgres server.  To permit external connections in the appropriate range add the following to `pg_hba.conf` (with appropriate choices for DATABASE, USER AND METHOD).

```
#TYPE   DATABASE   USER   ADDRESS          METHOD
host    all        all    172.17.0.0/16    scram-sha-256`
```

Also, by default the postgres server only listens on `localhost`, so you also need to tell postgres to listen on other IP addresses by adding the following to `postgresql.conf`.

`listen_addresses = '*'`